# Cookies not working

Tags: php, cookies

I am trying to get cookies to work on my site, to share variables between pages. But, they aren't working. Please check the code below and let me know if you see any issues...

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET["sid"]))
    { // Set cookie with URL variable
        setcookie( "sourceid", $_GET["sid"], time()+3600, "/" );
        $sid = $_GET["sid"];
    }  else {
        $sid = $_COOKIE['sourceid'];
    }

    if(isset($_GET["cid"]))
    { // if cookie exists
        setcookie( "categoryid", $_GET["cid"], time()+3600, "/" );  
        $cid = $_GET["cid"];
    }  else {
        $cid = $_COOKIE['categoryid'];
    }

    // Check
    echo "<!-- Show SID: ".$sid." -->"; // This works, on set page
    echo "<!-- Show CID: ".$cid." -->"; // This works, on set page
    echo "<!-- Show cookie SID: ".$_COOKIE["sourceid"]." -->"; // Doesn't work on any page
    echo "<!-- Show cookie CID: ".$_COOKIE["categoryid"]." -->"; // Doesn't work on any page
    ?>
```

Only the "Show SID" and "Show CID" comments work on the first page (with the variables in the URL). But none of the comments show variables on any pages I click to.

Comment: Make sure no output before calling `setcookie()`. Even before `<?php`

Comment: No output? So it has to be at the very top of the file?

Comment: No it can be at the bottom of the file, you just cant output before calling it.  You can however trap the output using the `ob_` functions.

Comment: I've tested your script, it works.

Comment: @Wils, right, I too tested your scripts. it's working fine. just add `print_r($_COOKIE)` to check what are the cookies assigned

Comment: When you say "output" ... what do you mean exactly. (I'm new to this coding thing)

Comment: Doing an echo is an output, and also those outside `<?php .. ?>` blocks are outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Mr. Blue. It's always the simple things. Need to set cookies at the very top of the document.

```
<?php
setcookie( "sourceid", $_GET["sid"], time()+3600, "/" );
?>
<html>
    <head>
         <body>
```

Comment: Apparently setcookie() failed because you were outputting html contents before calling setcookie().